# How to convert a Uni<Void> response to a "not found" in Quarkus Resteasy Reactive?

Tags: quarkus, resteasy, reactive, mutiny

Given an endpoint like that:

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
public Uni<Stuff> getSomeStuff(@PathParam("id") int id) {
   return someService.fetchStuff(id);
}
```

When `someService.fetchStuff(id)` returns an `Uni<Void>` the endpoints returns an empty HTTP response with status 204 (not found).

How can I get the endpoint to send an HTTP response with status 404 (not found) in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
public Uni<RestResponse<Stuff>> getSomeStuff(@PathParam("id") int id) {
   return someService.fetchStuff(id).onItem().transform(s -> {
            if (test(s)) {
                return RestResponse.ok(s);
            } else {
                return RestResponse.notFound();
            }
        })
}
```